# Web service equivalent name of Repository

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to know what name this class should be called.

I want to write classes that call third party web services, encapsulate them, and expose them for use in my own project. Below is the classes.

```
public class SForceService{

   public SForceService(ISForceRepository sForceRepository ){}

  //other logic here
}

public class SForceRepository{
    ISForceWrapper iSForceWrapper;
   IWebCfgManager webCfgManager;

   public SForceRepository(ISForceWrapper iSForceWrapper, IWebCfgManager webCfgManager){
     this.iSForceWrapper=iSForceWrapper;
      this.webCfgManager=webCfgManager;
   }

   //CRUD operation methods below
   public Contact GetContactById(int id){

     GetSessionId();

     var sql= "SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE id =" + id;
     return iSForceWrapper.Query<Contact>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
   }

   //create update, delete, etc
}
```

In the context of web service, is the name, `SForceRepository`, an appropriate name?

Comment: What is the name of the webservice? if it's just an API, you don't need to expose any indication that it's a web service, much like Repository doesn't indicate that you are accessing a database, flat file, in-memory etc...it's just another repository really.

Comment: The name of the web service is there, SForceService. I don't agree. Web service should be known it is web service. However, the focus of the question is the name of repository.

Comment: Repositories are sometimes called data providers. However, despite the implementation I still believe what you have IS a repository. Just call it XxxWebServiceRepository.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, Thanks! I think XxxWebServiceRepository is good. But I am wondering if there are other alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: @Pingpong, why should it be known? I guess thats down to the individuals preference, but ultimately you are getting data from a source, and therefore this is a repository. I would definitely get rid of the 'S', that doesn't seem to make much sense there? Will any other class implement the Interface that sits in front of the web service?

Comment: The name, SForceService, is an example only. No to your last question.